# strip javascript from string but keep CSS styles

Tags: vb.net

I generate some HTML dynamically and I need to make sure that any type of malicious javascript doesn't make it into the HTML.  So I have this code to "clean" the input before I save it to the database:

```
        Input = Input.Replace("'", "\'")
        Input = Input.Replace(Chr(34), "\" & Chr(34))
        Input = Input.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
        Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Input)
```

This does clean the input, but it is also stripping any inline CSS that I have inside the input.  Is there a way to strip out potentially malicious code yet keep the CSS tags?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe look specifically for `<script` instead of just any tags

Answer (score 1):

you can use this line

```
Private input = Regex.Replace(input, "<script.*?<\/script>|<script.*?\/>", "")
```